Semantic Kernel. 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'
I am trying Semantic Kernel with OpenAI in a Muai application. I am able to successfully get a simple prompt response using windows. However running under Android (emulator and local device) I get the error
Microsoft.SemanticKernel.HttpOperationException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
The following is the relevent code block, complete n Entry. Output goes to Label (Answer).
Error is raised at line:
var response = await kernel.InvokePromptAsync(((Entry)sender).Text);
As mentioned above code runs OK on Windows Machine but not on Android.
        public static IKernelBuilder builder = Kernel.CreateBuilder();
        public static Kernel kernel = builder
                 .AddOpenAIChatCompletion("gpt-4o-mini", OpenAI_Key)
                .Build();

private async void Question_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((Entry)sender).Text))
    {
        try
        {
            string request = ((Entry)sender).Text;
            ActivityIsRunning = true;
            var response = await kernel.InvokePromptAsync(((Entry)sender).Text);
            Answer.Text += $"You: {((Entry)sender).Text}{Environment.NewLine}AI: {response.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
            ((Entry)sender).Text = string.Empty;

            ActivityIsRunning = false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
}

Full exception as follows:
{Microsoft.SemanticKernel.HttpOperationException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
\---\> System.ClientModel.ClientResultException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
\---\> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
\---\> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
\---\> Interop+AndroidCrypto+SslException: Exception of type 'Interop+AndroidCrypto+SslException' was thrown.
\--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.d__1501\[\[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\]\].MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation1.d__1\[\[System.Net.Http.HttpConnection, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\]\].MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.HttpClientPipelineTransport.ProcessSyncOrAsync(PipelineMessage message, Boolean async)
\--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.HttpClientPipelineTransport.ProcessSyncOrAsync(PipelineMessage message, Boolean async)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.HttpClientPipelineTransport.ProcessCoreAsync(PipelineMessage message)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.PipelineTransport.ProcessSyncOrAsync(PipelineMessage message, Boolean async)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.PipelineTransport.ProcessAsync(PipelineMessage message)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.PipelineTransport.ProcessAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex) at System.ClientModel.Primitives.PipelinePolicy.ProcessNextAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.ApiKeyAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex) at System.ClientModel.Primitives.PipelinePolicy.ProcessNextAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.ClientRetryPolicy.ProcessSyncOrAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex, Boolean async) at System.ClientModel.Primitives.ClientRetryPolicy.ProcessSyncOrAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex, Boolean async)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.ClientRetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex) at GenericActionPipelinePolicy.ProcessAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex)
at OpenAI.GenericActionPipelinePolicy.ProcessAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex) at OpenAI.GenericActionPipelinePolicy.ProcessAsync(PipelineMessage message, IReadOnlyList1 pipeline, Int32 currentIndex)
at System.ClientModel.Primitives.ClientPipeline.SendAsync(PipelineMessage message)
at OpenAI.ClientPipelineExtensions.ProcessMessageAsync(ClientPipeline pipeline, PipelineMessage message, RequestOptions options)
at OpenAI.Chat.ChatClient.CompleteChatAsync(BinaryContent content, RequestOptions options)
at OpenAI.Chat.ChatClient.CompleteChatAsync(IEnumerable1 messages, ChatCompletionOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Connectors.OpenAI.ClientCore.\<RunRequestAsync\>d__651\[\[System.ClientModel.ClientResult1\[\[OpenAI.Chat.ChatCompletion, OpenAI, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4187f3e65366280\]\], System.ClientModel, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8\]\].MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Connectors.OpenAI.ClientCore.\<RunRequestAsync\>d__651\[\[System.ClientModel.ClientResult1\[\[OpenAI.Chat.ChatCompletion, OpenAI, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4187f3e65366280\]\], System.ClientModel, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8\]\].MoveNext()
at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Connectors.OpenAI.ClientCore.GetChatMessageContentsAsync(String targetModel, ChatHistory chat, PromptExecutionSettings executionSettings, Kernel kernel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.KernelFunctionFromPrompt.GetChatCompletionResultAsync(IChatCompletionService chatCompletion, Kernel kernel, PromptRenderingResult promptRenderingResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.KernelFunctionFromPrompt.InvokeCoreAsync(Kernel kernel, KernelArguments arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.KernelFunction.\<\>c__DisplayClass21_0.\<\<InvokeAsync\>b__0\>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Kernel.InvokeFilterOrFunctionAsync(NonNullCollection1 functionFilters, Func2 functionCallback, FunctionInvocationContext context, Int32 index)
at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Kernel.OnFunctionInvocationAsync(KernelFunction function, KernelArguments arguments, FunctionResult functionResult, Func2 functionCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.SemanticKernel.KernelFunction.InvokeAsync(Kernel kernel, KernelArguments arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at OpenAISematicKernal.SimpleResponse.Question_Completed(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\\VSProjects\\OpenAISematicKernalApp\\OpenAISematicKernal\\Views\\SimpleResponse.xaml.cs:line 42}
base: {System.Exception}
RequestMethod: (null)
RequestPayload: (null)
RequestUri: (null)
ResponseContent: (null)
StatusCode: null

I have search the internet and AI for a solution but unable to resolve.  As I don't have a problem with running on Windows I'm guessing something Android specific but don't know what.

There is a similar issue here. You can also try to change CheckCertificateRevocationList = true to CheckCertificateRevocationList = false and try again.

Unfortunately this does not help as it refers to a Web application, not Maui.
All the example I find use a Console application. As mentioned I don't have a problen in Windows, suggesting key etc. is not a problem.  Only a problem trying to run on Android.

i have the exact same issue.
